# load images function with Promise returns only last image

Tags: javascript

my code:

```
  const checkImagetest = images =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
       images.forEach(function (el) {
         let src = el.getAttribute("src");  console.log("src: ",src) // gives->src/hero.jpg src/hero1.jpg?v=1-0
         const img = new Image();
         img.onload = () => resolve(true);
         img.onerror = () => resolve(false);
         img.src =src;
       });
  });


const loadImgtest = (...images) => Promise.all(images.map(checkImagetest));

loadImgtest(document.querySelectorAll('[data-lg-loadImg]')).then(results => {
  console.log("results: ",results);    //gives->Array [ true ] (only the last src-value)
    if (results.every(res => res))     //The every() method returns true if the function returns true for all elements. The every() method returns false if the function returns false for one element.
        console.log('all [data-lg-loadImg]-images loaded successfully');
    else
        console.log('some [data-lg-loadImg]-images failed to load, all finished loading');
});
```

this do not work propper.
The .then(results => { ... gives only the last promise state back.
In the example it should has to be a array with lenght 2.
Whats wrong?

Comment: You need a Promise for all the images, not just a single promise for all the images.

Comment: You are looping over all of the images in the promise... it should just be the one you are loading in the map!

Comment: do you have some example html to test this json against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right basic idea, but you are not making a promise for each image. You are looping multiple times. The map should be looping over the images and you should not be looping over the images in the promise.

```js
function checkImg = el => 
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const src = el.getAttribute("src");
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(true);
    img.onerror = () => resolve(false);
    img.src =src;
  });

const images = document.querySelectorAll(...);

const promises = Array.from(images).map(checkImg);

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

Comment: Great answer. In addition, passing an array to a function and consuming that array with `(...images)` actually creates a 2-dimensional array, `[[img1, img2, img3]]`, which is messing with his logic - he only wants to use a 1-d array, like your code does.

Answer (score 0):

But this does not make any sense if the image has `src` since that would already be requested by the browser

Don't you mean something  like this?

```js
const checkImg = el => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (!el || !el.dataset || !el.dataset.src) {
    return reject(new Error("Invalid element or missing data-src attribute"));
  }
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    el.src = el.dataset.src; // Update the src attribute on load
    resolve(true);
  };
  img.onerror = () => resolve(false);
  img.src = el.dataset.src; // Load the image
});

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const images = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-src]")];

  if (images.length === 0) {
    console.log("No elements with [data-src] found.");
  } else {
    const promises = images.map(checkImg);

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.png&text=dummy" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/f00.png&text=Actual1">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.png&text=dummy" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/ff1.png&text=Actual2">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.png&text=dummy" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/f0a.png&text=Actual3">
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
    const preloadImages = (selector = '[data-lg-loadImg]') => {
    return Promise.all(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).map(el => {
        const img = new Image();
              img.src = el.getAttribute("src");
        if (img.complete)
            return Promise.resolve(img.naturalHeight !== 0);
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(true));
            img.addEventListener('error', () => resolve(false));
        });
    }))
};

preloadImages().then(results => {
    if (results.every(res => res))     //geht nur mit true/false   The every() method returns true if the function returns true for all elements. The every() method returns false if the function returns false for one element.
        console.log('---------------all [data-lg-loadImg]-images loaded successfully');
    else
        console.log('----------------some [data-lg-loadImg]-images failed to load, all finished loading');
});
```

I this the way it works?